# BigQuery extract week as date range from date field

Tags: google-bigquery

I want to extract the week as date range from a `DATETIME` field in bigquery.
From [these docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions) I can extract the week as a week number like this
`EXTRACT(WEEK FROM date)`, or get the first day as date like this `DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK)`

But what if I want to get a date range, for example if the date field have the value `2021-12-23 04:30:00` and say Sunday is the first the of the week, I would like to get this result `2021-12-19 - 2021-12-25`
or something similar. Is it possible?

Comment: as a single column with type string, or two separate columns each with type date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your desired output, separate columns or single string, you can try the following:

```
with sample_data as (
    SELECT date FROM UNNEST(generate_timestamp_array('2021-12-01 00:00:00', '2022-02-01 00:00:00', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as date
)

select
    date
    , DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK) week_start
    , DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK) +6 week_end
    , LAST_DAY(DATE(date), WEEK) as alt_week_end
    , concat(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK)," - ", DATE_TRUNC(DATE(date), WEEK) +6) week_range
from sample_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  date_trunc(date(date), week) week_start,
  last_day(date(date), week) week_end
from your_table
```

with output like

[image]